# how to make perl to properly recognize <% marks

Tags: perl, apache, configuration, shorttags

I have to continue an existing project in perl, but I'am a newbie and I ran into a problem what I can't resolve.
The code is full with this kind of syntax

```
if ( $Session->{CurrentUserEntityId} )
{
  %>

  <%=&get_leftnav_html('index')%>

  <div class="mainContent">

    <!-- 
    The following tile colors are accepted:
    #A200FF, #FF0097, #00ABA9, #8CBF26, #A05000, #E671B8, #F09609, #1BA1E2, #E51400, #339933
    -->

    <div class="tile_container">
        <div class="tile">
            (...)
        </div>
```

and so on...
On the server everything is right, but I can run the code on my localhost, because I get this error in the apache error log:

> [error] Unterminated <> operator at
>   /var/www/piqresearch/piqresearch/marketData/htdocs/index.pl line 1.\n

If I write open <% and the %> into the same line, then the perl accept it, but it's die at the next occurrence and the project contains many hundreds of files and maybe many thousand of this mark. I searched on the net for the solution, in articles, tutorials and here on the Stack Overflow, but I found nothing. I think it's just some kind of configuration error, but I can't find what should I do.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: `<% ... %>` is not core Perl. Are you using Classic ASP with PerlScript? Mason? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not Perl; that's a [Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/) template. You'll need to use the Mason to process your template, not Perl.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I didn't know.